# Python Pygame image not displaying

Tags: python, image, pygame

I am trying to display a game in pygame. But it won't work for some reason, any ideas? Here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
p = 1
green = (0,255,0)
pacman ="imgres.jpeg"
pacman_x = 0
pacman_y = 0
while True:
    pacman_obj=pygame.image.load(pacman).convert()
    screen.blit(pacman_obj, (pacman_x,pacman_y))
    blue = (0,0,255)
    screen.fill(blue)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                p=0
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: > "it wont work for some reason"

Do you have anything a little more specific?  What is happening currently?

Do you have a line like this before all of this code?: `os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'`  This is one of the things you need for pygame to work.

Comment: I have never used `os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'`, so I don't think its something "you need for pygame to work".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a guess, as I haven't actually ran this:

Is the screen just showing up blue and you're missing the pacman image? What might be happening is that you are blitting pacman onto the screen, and then doing a screen.fill(blue), which is essentially overwriting your pacman image with blue. Try reversing these steps in your code (that is, filling the screen blue, then blitting pacman after).

Answer (score 2):

if the screen shows up blue, it is because you need to "blit" the image after you do `screen.fill`

also, blue has to be defined at the top, and it should be in a different loop. here is how i would do it:

```
    import pygame, sys
    from pygame.locals import *
    pygame.init()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)
    pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
    p = 1
    green = (0,255,0)
    blue = (0,0,255)
    pacman ="imgres.jpeg"
    pacman_x = 0
    pacman_y = 0
    pacman_obj=pygame.image.load(pacman).convert()
    done = False
    clock=pygame.time.Clock()
    while done==False:
        for event in pygame.event.get(): 
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done=True
            if event.type==KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==K_LEFT:
                    p=0
        screen.fill(blue)
        screen.blit(pacman_obj, (pacman_x,pacman_y))

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(100)

    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Note:

- You are creating a new image every frame. This is slow.
- Coordinates for blit can be `Rect()`s

Here's updated code.

```
WINDOW_TITLE = "hi world - draw image "

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
import random
import os

class Pacman(Sprite):
    """basic pacman, deriving pygame.sprite.Sprite"""
    def __init__(self, file=None):
        """create surface"""
        Sprite.__init__(self)
        # get main screen, save for later
        self.screen = pygame.display.get_surface()                

        if file is None: file = os.path.join('data','pacman.jpg')
        self.load(file)

    def draw(self):
        """draw to screen"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def load(self, filename):
        """load file"""
        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()      

class Game(object):
    """game Main entry point. handles intialization of game and graphics, as well as game loop"""    
    done = False
    color_bg = Color('seagreen') # or also: Color(50,50,50) , or: Color('#fefefe')

    def __init__(self, width=800, height=600):
        """Initialize PyGame window.

        variables:
            width, height = screen width, height
            screen = main video surface, to draw on

            fps_max     = framerate limit to the max fps
            limit_fps   = boolean toggles capping FPS, to share cpu, or let it run free.
            color_bg    = backround color, accepts many formats. see: pygame.Color() for details
        """
        pygame.init()

        # save w, h, and screen
        self.width, self.height = width, height
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(( self.width, self.height ))
        pygame.display.set_caption( WINDOW_TITLE )        

        # fps clock, limits max fps
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.limit_fps = True
        self.fps_max = 40        

        self.pacman = Pacman()

    def main_loop(self):
        """Game() main loop.
        Normally goes like this:

            1. player input
            2. move stuff
            3. draw stuff
        """
        while not self.done:
            # get input            
            self.handle_events()

            # move stuff            
            self.update()

            # draw stuff
            self.draw()

            # cap FPS if: limit_fps == True
            if self.limit_fps: self.clock.tick( self.fps_max )
            else: self.clock.tick()

    def draw(self):
        """draw screen"""
        # clear screen."
        self.screen.fill( self.color_bg )

        # draw code
        self.pacman.draw()

        # update / flip screen.
        pygame.display.flip()

    def update(self):
        """move guys."""
        self.pacman.rect.left += 10

    def handle_events(self):
        """handle events: keyboard, mouse, etc."""
        events = pygame.event.get()

        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: self.done = True
            # event: keydown
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE: self.done = True

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    game = Game()
    game.main_loop()
```

Answer (score -1):

## First you blit the image and then fill it with BLUE ,so it might show only blue screen ,

Solution: First fill screen blue and then blit it.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
p = 1
green = (0,255,0)
pacman ="imgres.jpeg"
pacman_x = 0
pacman_y = 0
while True:
    pacman_obj=pygame.image.load(pacman).convert()
    
    blue = (0,0,255)
    screen.fill(blue)   # first fill screen with blue
    screen.blit(pacman_obj, (pacman_x,pacman_y))  # Blit the iamge
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                p=0
    pygame.display.update()
```